# Randomly select from a list while ensuring the selected elements value must be x apart

Tags: python

Say I have a list

```
l = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7]
```

Given the list above, I have 15 elements, 8 unique elements, I need to sample n number of indices of the elements that are random but are **at least x apart in value**. For example, if `n = 4` and `x = 2`, some possibilities are (note that the order of the `indices` can be in any order, I gave them in ascending order for more simple understanding):

```
# the randomly selected elements are [0, 2, 4, 7], while their respective indices are:
indices = [0, 5, 7, 14]

# the randomly selected elements are [1, 3, 5, 7], while their respective indices are:
indices = [3, 6, 11, 14]
```

And in the case where it's not possible to draw n number of x apart indices (where in this case above, `n = 5`, `x = 2`, the remaining indices (in this case, the remaining 1 index) could be from any random element that hasn't been picked yet. And if there's none left to pick from, the length of `indices` would be `n - remaining` (effectively mean no need to pick anymore, keep what is picked).

I don't know whether one could call is a truly random sampling, but what are some approach to this problem? Efficiency is also paramount in this case as many calls will be made.

Comment: Can you explain bit more clearly

Comment: It's interesting that the "randomly" selected values are all in ascending order. Is that just by chance? Also, why (in the 2nd example) is the output not [3, 6, 8, 14] ?

Comment: @CtrlZ in my real case they are actually in ascending order, but is that matter? `[3, 6, 8, 14]` could also be one of the possibility as they're still x=2 apart, I just gave one of many the possibilities.

Comment: @GregorIsack If, in the real case, the outputs are always ascending then the concept of randomness is moot

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood you first comment, I thought you meant the `l`. Actually it doesn't really matter if the `indices` are in what order, I guess I just gave them in ascending order because it's simple to understands.

Comment: If n = 2 and x = 4, can elements `[1, 5, 1]` from indices `[4, 8, 4]` be valid?

Comment: if n = 2, the maximum indices length would be 2, so the valid elements (from the example you gave) would be `[1, 5]` and `indices = [4, 8]`

Comment: Oops I meant to say n.= 3. My point was to ask if going back and forth in values be valid.

Comment: In that case, it would be a partially valid case, since it's not possible to obtain 3 completely "apart" x=4 indices, so the last one could pick any random index from the whole list which hasn't been picked yet (sorry I forgot to mention this in the question! Edited.).

Answer (score 1):

I would (naively?) do this as my first attempt. What we are going to do as a first step is try to find `number_required` "random" elements with the given `minimum_delta` constraint and failing that we will backfill if we can.

At both stages we will re-construct a `candidates` list of the valid choices remaining and randomly pick one.

With luck we can construct our desired results:

```py
import random

def get_sample_indexes(data_length, sample_length, minimum_delta):
    ## --------------------
    ## Exit fast if we want a sample that is at least the
    ## size of our data
    ## --------------------
    if data_length <= sample_length:
        result_indexes = list(range(data_length))
        ## random.shuffle(result_indexes)
        return result_indexes
    ## --------------------

    data_indexes = set(range(data_length))
    result_indexes = set()

    ## --------------------
    ## Identify as many randomly selected items that are at least
    ## minimum_delta apart until we have sample_length or until
    ## there are no longer valid choices left
    ## --------------------
    while len(result_indexes) <= sample_length:
        candidates = [i for i in data_indexes if all(abs(i-j) >= minimum_delta for j in result_indexes)]
        if not candidates:
            break
        result_indexes.add(random.choice(candidates))
    ## --------------------

    ## --------------------
    ## If we still don't have enough items backfill without the delta constraint
    ## --------------------
    if len(result_indexes) < sample_length:
        candidates = list(data_indexes - result_indexes)
        result_indexes.update(random.sample(candidates, sample_length - len(result_indexes)))
    ## --------------------

    ## --------------------
    ## return a our list of results
    ## --------------------
    result_indexes = list(result_indexes)
    ## random.shuffle(result_indexes)
    return result_indexes
    ## --------------------

data = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7]
data_length = len(data)

results = get_sample_indexes(data_length, 4, 2)
print(f"{results=}")

results = get_sample_indexes(data_length, 8, 2)
print(f"{results=}")

results = get_sample_indexes(data_length, 40, 2)
print(f"{results=}")
```

That will give you results like:

```
results=[0, 2, 4, 9, 13]
results=[0, 1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 11, 12, 14]
results=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

Comment: This is intuitive. However seems like the sample produced an additionally length. If `sample_length = 4`, then `len(results)` should be 4 as well (in the examples, it's `sample_length + 1`). Seems like the mistake is at `while len(result_indexes) <= sample_length` line, changing to less than fixed them.

Comment: Wait, looks like `data` is not used. So it just randomly picks unrelated elements?

Comment: Do you need the separation of items based on item values or item indexes? You say "draw n number of x apart indices" which suggests to me that the values of the list items do not factor in here.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach I can think of right now would be to create a dict with the values as the keys and an array of indices as the value. Then loop on the keys in ascending order to create a sample of n values at least x apart. Finally pick one of the indices in the dict for each of the values.

**/!\ This solution is quite naive, might not the most optimized and does not give you all solutions.**

Code example :

```
from typing import Dict, List

s = 4
x = 2
l = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7]

# Create a dict with the values as key and array of indices as value
# Complexity : O(n)

index_dict: Dict[int, List[int]] = {}

for i, value in enumerate(l):
    if value in index_dict.keys():
        index_dict[value].append(i)
    else:
        index_dict[value] = [i]

# index_dict = {0: [0, 1, 2], 1: [3, 4], 2: [5], 3: [6], 4: [7], 5: [8, 9, 10, 11], 6: [12, 13], 7: [14]}

# Create a list of disctinct values
# Complexity : O(n*log(n))

distinct_values = sorted(index_dict.keys())
# distinct_values = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

# Loop distinct values to get a sample of s values x apart
# Complexity : O(n)

current_value = distinct_values[0]
sample_values = [current_value]

for value in distinct_values[1:]:
    if value - current_value >= x:
        sample_values.append(value)
        current_value = value
    if len(sample_values) == s:
        break

# sample_values = [0, 2, 4, 6]

# Get the indices of the sample values randomly
# Complexity : O(n)

sample_indices = []
for value in sample_values:
    sample_indices.append(random.choice(index_dict[value]))

# sample_indices = [0, 5, 7, 13] or [2, 5, 7, 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate from the list of candidates all elements that are between value-x and value+x, at each draw reducing the number of possible candidates. But because you might have to backtrack to fill the selection of n elements, you store a list of deleted elements to use if you get to that point.

something like this:

```py
n = ...  #number of elements to select
x = ...  # imposed margin
l = ...  # list of elements

candidates = np.array(l)
selected = []
deleted = []
while candidates:
    choice = np.random.randint(len(candidates))
    selected.append(candidates[choice])
    to_delete = np.logical_and(candidates<candidates[choice]+x, candidates>candidates[choice]-x)
    to_delete[choice] = False  # don't flag the selected element as deleted
    deleted.extend(candidates[to_delete])
    to_delete[choice] = True  # now it can be deleted from candidates
    candidates = candidates[~to_delete]

if len(selected) < n:
    candidates = np.concatenate([candidates, deleted]) # get deleted elements back in there
    choices = np.random.randint(0, len(candidates), size=n-len(selected))
    for c in choices:
        selected.append(candidates[c])
```

Answer (score 0):

This code find *all* possible sublist of size `n` spaced by at least `x` values.

Random sampling and `x` too large cases can be easily derived and are omitted.

```
from itertools import combinations, product
from operator import itemgetter


l = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7]

n = 4
x = 2

# map value to list of indices
values_inidices_mapper = {}
for i, v in enumerate(l):
    values_inidices_mapper.setdefault(v, []).append(i)

u = sorted(set(l))
# return n values spaced by at least x
values = []
for c in combinations(u, r=n):       
    if all(r-l>=x for l, r in combinations(c, r=2)):
        values.append(c)

# space of indices organized per possible values
for vs in values:  
    space_of_indices = product(*itemgetter(*vs)(values_inidices_mapper))
    print(*space_of_indices, sep='\n')        
    print()
```

---

Choosing random elements required to cast first the generator into a sequence and this step is expensive. Here two examples:

1. For a random selection `k` unique elements replace the last block of code with

```
from itertools import chain # and the others...
#[...]
# amount of selections
k = 4

selections = random.sample(
    list(chain.from_iterable(product(*itemgetter(*vs)(values_inidices_mapper)) for vs in values)),
    k=k
)

print(*selections, sep='\n')
```

This approach could be *quite expensive* because it flats the whole "set" of possible possibilities but it gives "true" random selection.

2. Alternatively, **if** a compromise with efficiency and random selection is possible you can try a kind of *block-wise randomisation*

```
from itertools import combinations, product
from operator import itemgetter
import random

# fix randomness - debugging mode
random.seed(123456)

l = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7]
n = 4
x = 2
# amount of selections                     <-- new dependency
k = 8

# map value to list of indices
values_inidices_mapper = {}
for i, v in enumerate(l):
    values_inidices_mapper.setdefault(v, []).append(i)

# shuffle the indices in-place                 <-- random
for k, v in values_inidices_mapper.items():
    random.shuffle(v)

u = sorted(set(l))
# return n values spaced by at least x
values = []
for c in combinations(u, r=n):       
    if all(r-l>=x for l, r in combinations(c, r=2)):
        values.append(c)

# shuffle the possible values in-place
random.shuffle(values)                       # <-- random
indices = []
# space of indices organized per possible values
for vs in values:
    space_of_indices = list(product(*itemgetter(*vs)(values_inidices_mapper)))
    random.shuffle(space_of_indices)         # <-- random
    for i in space_of_indices:
        if k <= 0:
            break
        indices.append(i)
        k -= 1
    if k <= 0:
        break
else:
    raise Exception('[FAIL] Excpected amount of selection is greater than the amount of possibilites')

print(*indices, sep='\n')
```

Comment: This approach seems ingenious. Is it possible for the last bit to just generate a random single possibility each time? Since getting all possible indices at one sampling unnecessary. I guess I could add additionally line of code to randomly pick one of them for each loop, but I'm curious what would you do?

Comment: Also, this approach seems to failed when `n = 5`, `x = 2` as mentioned in my post.

Comment: @Gregor Isack thanks for the feedback, I will try to fix this evening

Comment: No, my program doesn't fail, it's just that that case is not covered by the program as mentioned in the description. PS I haven't quite gotten the part _"the remaining indices [...]"_